# MySQL: LEFT JOIN, MAX not allowed in ON or WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, max, left-join

Lets look at the tables:

```
tbl_specimen
specimen_id | create | specimen_gid | specimen_name | specimen_owner
1 |01.01.2015| 1000 | Banafone | John
2 |03.01.2015| 1000 | Modified Banafone | John
3 |05.01.2015| 1001 | Cucumberfone | John
3 |06.01.2015| 1002 | Cherryfone | Mike
```

The GID is a unique number for the item. So specimen_id and specimen_id are the same, but in different versions. These items have to be checked.

```
tbl_qualitycheck
check_id | checked_specimenid | check_date | check_result
2001 | 1| 02.01.2015 | good
2002 | 3| 06.01.2015 | good
```

As you see the current version of GID1000 is not checked (no check for specimen_id=2)

```
Wanted result
1000 | Modified Banafone | NULL <= because current version is not checked
1001 | Cucumberfone | good
```

I startet to get it running with:

```
SELECT 
   tbl_specimen.specimen_gid,
   max(tbl_specimen.specimen_id) as max_specimen_id,
   tbl_specimen.specimen_name
FROM
   tbl_specimen
WHERE
  tbl_specimen.specimen_owner = "John"
GROUP BY
  tbl_specimen.specimen_gid;
```

As result I got the current version of the item. In the next step I wanted to enrich the table with the tbl_qualitycheck.
I inserted a

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_qualitycheck ON checked_specimenid = max_specimen_id
```

after the FROM - part and got an error
Then I tested:

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_qualitycheck ON checked_specimenid = MAX(specimen_id)
```

...and got an error
I read that max is not allout in the ON or in the WHERE clauses, but I don't have an idea to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select tq.* --change this selection to be more appropriate 
from 
(
SELECT 
tbl_specimen.specimen_gid
max(tbl_specimen.specimen_id) as max_specimen_id
tbl_specimen.specimen_name
FROM tbl_specimen
WHERE tbl_specimen.specimen_owner = "John"
GROUP BY tbl_specimen.specimen_gid) t
left join tbl_qualitycheck tq on tq.checked_specimenid = t.max_specimen_id
```

As you can't use a calculated column in a `join` clause (if it is an aggregated result), you should have it as a sub-query and then `join` on the tables needed.

Comment: I needed some minutes to understand, what's going on, but now I got the clue. ThanX.

Comment: No, it is just an alias for the table `tbl_qualitycheck`. You can name it anything you want.